# How to update product quantity after order was placed in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTU0P.png)

[Product Attribute Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7RDY.png)

My PostOrder Function

```
        public function getPaymentStatus(Request $request){

        if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $user_email = Auth::user()->email;

        //get shipping details
        $shippingDetails = DeliveryAddress::where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->first();

        $order = new Order;
        $order->user_id = $user_id;
        $order->user_email = $user_email;
        $order->name = $shippingDetails->name;
        $order->address = $shippingDetails->address;
        $order->city = $shippingDetails->city;
        $order->state = $shippingDetails->state;
        $order->country = $shippingDetails->country;
        $order->postcode = $shippingDetails->postcode;
        $order->mobile = $shippingDetails->mobile;
        $order->coupon_code = $coupon_code;
        $order->coupon_amount = $coupon_amount;
        $order->order_status = "New";
        $order->grand_total = Session::get('grand_total');
        $order->save();

        $order_id = DB::getPdo()->lastInsertId();

        $cartProducts = DB::table('cart')->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->get();
        foreach($cartProducts as $pro){
            $cartPro = new OrdersProduct;
            $cartPro->order_id = $order_id;
            $cartPro->user_id = $user_id;
            $cartPro->product_id = $pro->product_id;
            $cartPro->product_code = $pro->product_code;
            $cartPro->product_name = $pro->product_name;
            $cartPro->product_size = $pro->size;
            $cartPro->product_color =  $pro->product_color;
            $cartPro->product_price = $pro->price;
            $cartPro->product_qty = $pro->quantity;
            $cartPro->save();
        }
        return redirect('/thank-you');
      }
```

i have a table "products" which store product details and a table "products_attribute" which store the stock of the product. I don't know how link this to products_attribute table. Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have a grasp of `Eloquent` Models with your `Order` and `DeliveryAddress` model.

To setup relationships between your `Product` and `Product Attribute` simply define the relationship method inside your `Product` model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('ProductAttribute');
    }
}
```

Eloquent will use snake case in determining the name of foreign key, which in this case would be `product_id`.  If your foreign key is defined differently you may specify the name as a second argument:

```
return $this->hasMany('ProductAttribute', 'my_product_id');
```

If you want to have a relationship from `ProductAttribute` to `Product` use the `belongsTo` method:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProductAttribute extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product');
    }
}
```

You may also specify a custom foreign key name similar to the `hasMany` method:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'my_product_id');
```

To update the quauntity you could do something like this:

```
foreach($cartProducts as $pro){
        $cartPro = new OrdersProduct;
        $cartPro->order_id = $order_id;
        $cartPro->user_id = $user_id;
        $cartPro->product_id = $pro->product_id;
        $cartPro->product_code = $pro->product_code;
        $cartPro->product_name = $pro->product_name;
        $cartPro->product_size = $pro->size;
        $cartPro->product_color =  $pro->product_color;
        $cartPro->product_price = $pro->price;
        $cartPro->product_qty = $pro->quantity;
        $cartPro->save();

        $product = Product::find($pro->product_id);

        if (null !== $product) {
            // you will need a sku or some other unique identifier
            // from your attribute to determine the correct attribute
            // to modify after your order is complete
            $attribute = $product->attributes()-where('sku', $sku)->first();
            $attribute->quantity = $attribute->quantity - $pro->quantity;
            $attribute->save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: after done this how to minus the quantity of stock in the product_attribute table ya? After the order placed, then it will take the each $pro->quantity and minus with each product's stock in product_attribute table.

Comment: @AdamLim You will need to find your product, then loop through your attributes, and possible use the sku or whatever unique identifier you have for the attributes, then once found perform the quantity subtraction.

Comment: im not sure how to write it. because at first im writing like this. DB::table('productsAttribute')->where('product_id',$pro->product_id)->decrement('stock', $pro->quantity);

Comment: but then i realize that it wont minus the products as i wish. can you show how to write in foreach statement?

Comment: @AdamLim I have updated the answer to show how you might go about updating your attribute.

Comment: Yes you can, but how would you determine which one to update if you have two attributes to one product?

Comment: Hi bro, thanks i had already solve the problem.  i just use this  ProductsAttribute::where('sku',$pro->product_code)->decrement('stock',$pro->quantity); sku and product_code is unique

Comment: I see `product_code` is your `sku`? No problem. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

you should use relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships)

first you create ProductModel
after that you create one method like attributes
and use hasMany relationships
so you can do whatever you want